# Transfer data from a Javascript object to an array. What's wrong with my array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

We need to transfer the data from the javascript `object` to the left into an `array`. Initialize a new `array` called `userDataArray` and add all of the data from the `object` into the `array` by calling it from the `object` using the number keys that have been added to the `object`.

When you are done, you should have the same data from the `object` that has already been written, but in an `array`, without having to retype each of the variables separately.

```
var userData = {
  1: true,
  2: true,
  3: "00QRA10",
  4: "slimer42",
  5: "FFASN9111871-USN16"
};

var userDataArray = [0,1,2,3,4];
```

Comment: it looks like homework, what have you tried?

Comment: It is a homework challenge. The second var is my answer. var userDataArray = [0,1,2,3,4];

Comment: I don't understand _"from the javascript object **to the left** into an array_ - What exactly is to transfer to the left? And did you read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) about the methods of object?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is clearly a homework.

Comment: Sorry, didn't even think about that wording. To the left is how it is displayed on the assignment. The object on the left is var userData = {
  1: true,
  2: true,
  3: "00QRA10",
  4: "slimer42",
  5: "FFASN9111871-USN16"
};

Comment: @batman091716 ... following the advice of Alon you will find [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) that might help you getting started. If you come back with an approach of your own, like Nina does suggest, she most probably will take an(y) effort in order to further help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want but...

```js
var userData = {
  1: true,
  2: true,
  3: "00QRA10",
  4: "slimer42",
  5: "FFASN9111871-USN16"
};

var outputArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(userData).length; i++) {
  outputArray.push(userData[Object.keys(userData)[i]]);
}
console.log(outputArray);
```

taking it apart: `Object.keys(userData)` is the list (array) of key names. In this case it is 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. `outputArray.push()` adds an element to the array. `Object.keys(userData)[i]` is the name of the object element that we're on, and `userData[Object.keys(userData)[i]]` is just the element that we're on. So every time we go through the for loop, we add another element to the array.

Your example uses 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 for their element names though, so something like this might work better:

```js
var userData = {
  1: true,
  2: true,
  3: "00QRA10",
  4: "slimer42",
  5: "FFASN9111871-USN16"
};

var outputArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(userData).length; i++) {
  outputArray.push(userData[i+1]);
}
console.log(outputArray);
```

In this example, instead of taking the element name out of the key array we assume that it is a number and that the numbers are in a sequence that starts with 1.

## The reason why your solution didn't work

is because you didn't call the numbers from the object. You would've had to use `userData.1`, `userData.2`, `userData.3`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use new function like Object.values to get values from object, and Object.keys to get keys from the object.

```
var userData = {
  1: true,
  2: true,
  3: "00QRA10",
  4: "slimer42",
  5: "FFASN9111871-USN16"
};

var userDataArray = Object.values(userData)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through an object and use the keys to get the values.

```js
var userData = {
  1: true,
  2: true,
  3: "00QRA10",
  4: "slimer42",
  5: "FFASN9111871-USN16"
};

var userDataArray = [];

for (var key in userData) {
  userDataArray.push(userData[key])
}

console.log(userDataArray)
```